# Spring Integration Gateway reply channel when method return is void

Tags: methods, integration, spring-integration, void, gateway

I've questions/clarifications-to-make regarding SI gateway feature:

If my gateway interface is defined as below:

```
public interface MyGateway{
   public void myGatewayMethod(Message<?> inMessage);
}
```

And my gateway configuration defined as below:

```
<int:gateway id="mySvcGateway"
                 service-interface="com.myCompany.myPkg.MyGateway"
                 error-channel="globalExceptionHandlerChannel">

        <int:method name="myGatewayMethod" request-channel="myGatewayReqChannel" />     
    </int:gateway>
```

My questions/clarifications-to-make are :

1) Since the gateway service interface method is returning void, does the Gateway proxy bean still look for a response on the "default-reply-channel" or the user defined "reply-channel" ?

2) In other words, do I still need to mention `reply-channel="nullChannel"` (or `default-reply-channel="nullChannel"`) ?

OR

since the method return is void, gateway automatically will understand no to listen to the reply channel ?

3) Can I still add `reply-timeout` attribute to this configuration OR it will not make sense since there is no reply expected ?

In similar context, if I add another method in the service interface method as below:

```
public interface MyGateway{
       public void myGatewayMethod(Message<?> inMessage);
       public Object myGatewayMethod2(Message<?> inMessage);
    }
```

and add this method in my gateway config as below:

```
<int:gateway id="mySvcGateway"
                     service-interface="com.myCompany.myPkg.MyGateway"
                     error-channel="globalExceptionHandlerChannel">

            <int:method name="myGatewayMethod" request-channel="myGatewayReqChannel" /> 
<int:method name="myGatewayMethod2" request-channel="myGatewayReqChannel2" />   
        </int:gateway>
```

4) In this case I would believe I need to define `reply-channel`, correct ?

5) The `default-reply-channel` may not work for this case as for one method gateway expects a response and not for other, correct ?

6) If yes, then for the method that returns void, do I need to explicitly mention `reply-channel="nullChannel"` ?

Thanks to confirm.

Comment: Can someone pls help me out on above clarifications ? Artem/Garry - Looking for your kind attn ! Many thanks !

Comment: OK, Lalit. I'm starring your question and take a look today :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lalit!

Thank for such a big bunch of question and I'm surprised that all of them are around the gateway's `void` method.

The quick reasonable answer to all of them is:

Since we don't say in the Reference Manual anything on the matter, there is no worries for such a configuration and it should work as expected by the
faith in Spring Integration.

I'm joking a bit, but every joke has a part of truth.

Now let's take a look to the source code of `GatewayProxyFactoryBean`:

```
 private Object invokeGatewayMethod(MethodInvocation invocation, boolean runningOnCallerThread) throws Exception {
    ..........
    boolean shouldReply = returnType != void.class;
    ..................
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        if (shouldReply) {
            response = shouldReturnMessage ? gateway.sendAndReceiveMessage(args) : gateway.sendAndReceive(args);
        }
        else {
            gateway.send(args);
            response = null;
        }
    }
    return (response != null) ? this.convert(response, returnType) : null;
}
```

Where `MessagingGatewaySupport.send()` delegates to the

```
this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(requestChannel, object, this.historyWritingPostProcessor);
```

which is `void`, too, and just calls in the end `MessageChannel.send()`.

As you may guess this method doesn't care about `replyChannel` and `replyTimeout` at all.

Logically it assumes that those options will be just ignored for the `void` method and any `default-*` for other methods doesn't impact those with `void` return type.

Hope I am clear.

Comment: Many tx Artem; your clarifications are crystal clear ! But then how can i achieve the time out functionality for void methods similar to what "replyTimeout" provides for non-void method ? I do not want my threads to unnecessarily stuck for long processing time. Also I want to avoid using any kind of inbound channel adapters.

Comment: We need timeout exactly in an `async` case, when we wait for the reply. If your request-reply case is sync there won't be any timeout involved. For the stuck Thread it doesn't matter if it is just `send` or `send` part of `sendAndReceive`. Try to imagine your use-case without SI and you'll see that there is just no any tool to help you to stop Thread itself.

Comment: Sometimes we can make our life easy by avoiding unnecessary complexities ! :) Thanks Artem !

Comment: Knowing that a `void` return value essentially turns the "gateway" into an "adapter" like thing should be mentioned in the documentation!